# In angularjs dynamic button creation is correct but validation is not correct

Tags: angularjs, validation

in my code  buttons are  created correctly but after typing the first row,click Add fields.the close button is disabled in first row.but i want only disable in current typing row.other close buttons are enable.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="okay.js">
 </script>
 </head>
<body ng-app="testApp">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<form name="frm" class="form-inline" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="string"  name="cat_name" class="form-control" ng-model="cat_name" placeholder="Enter Category Name"     ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group"> 
<input type="text" name="cat_desc" class="form-control" ng-model="cat_desc" placeholder="Enter Your Description" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" required>
</div> <br>
<fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index ">
    <br>
    <div class="form-group"> <input type="text" ng-model="choice.itemName" class="form-control" name="item_name" placeholder="Category Item Name" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" required> 


    <div class="form-group">      
           <input type="text" ng-model="choice.itemDesc" class="form-control" name="item_desc" placeholder="Category Description" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" required>

  </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="number" ng-model="choice.itemView" class="form-control" name="item_count" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]/"placeholder="Category Item View Count" required>
<p class="help-block" ng-show="frm.item_count.$error.pattern">numbers only allowed</p>  
    <select id="country" ng-model="choice.states" name="state" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries">
      </div>

    <div class="form-group"> 
    <option value=''>Choose</option>
        </select>City:
        <select id="state" ng-disabled="!choice.states" name="city" ng-model="one">
            <option value="">Choose</option>
            <option ng-repeat="state in choice.states" value="{{state.id}}">{{state.city}}</option>
        </select>
     </div>
        <button ng-click="removeChoice()" class="remove btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="!frm.item_name.$dirty||!frm.item_desc.$dirty||!frm.item_count.$dirty||!frm.state.$dirty||!frm.city.$dirty||frm.item_name.$invalid||frm.item_desc.$invalid">close</button>
   </fieldset>
   <br>
   <button class="addfields btn btn-success" ng-click="addNewChoice()"  ng-disabled="!frm.item_name.$dirty||!frm.item_desc.$dirty||!frm.item_count.$dirty||!frm.state.$dirty||!frm.city.$dirty||frm.item_name.$invalid||frm.item_desc.$invalid">Add fields</button>
     <button class="addfields btn btn-success"   ng-disabled="!frm.item_name.$dirty||!frm.item_desc.$dirty||!frm.item_count.$dirty||!frm.state.$dirty||!frm.city.$dirty||frm.item_name.$invalid||frm.item_desc.$invalid " >Save</button>

 <span class="help-block" style="color:red"ng-show="frm.cat_desc.$error.pattern" style:"color:red">ERROR:<BR/>text only allowed</span >
  <span class="help-block" style="color:red"ng-show="frm.item_desc.$error.pattern">ERROR:<BR/>text only allowed</span >  
  <span class="help-block" style="color:red"ng-show="frm.cat_name.$error.pattern">ERROR:<BR/>text only allowed</span >
     <span class="help-block"style="color:red" ng-show="frm.item_name.$error.pattern">ERROR:<BR/>text only allowed</span > </div>
   <div id="choicesDisplay">
      {{ newItemNo }}
   </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

okay. js (angular File)

```
var app=angular.module('testApp', []);
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];





  $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
    var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
    $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});

};

  $scope.removeChoice = function() {
    $scope.choices.splice(this.$index,1);
  };


     $scope.countries = {
         'Andhra': [{
             'id': '01',
             'city': "Guntur"
         }, {
             'id': '02',
             'city': "Hyderabad"
         }],
             'Tamilnadu': [{
             'id': '03',
             'city': "CBE"
         }, {
             'id': '04',
             'dep': "Trichy"
         }]
     };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a few issues in your HTML that I cleaned up but primarily your issue was that you needed to perform your validation on just the current row.  So you can add an ng-form attribute along with your ng-repeat to create a scope per row.  The resulting HTL looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="okay.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<form name="frm" class="form-inline" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="string" name="cat_name" class="form-control" ng-model="cat_name" placeholder="Enter Category Name" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="cat_desc" class="form-control" ng-model="cat_desc" placeholder="Enter Your Description" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" required>
  </div>
  <br>
  <fieldset data-ng-repeat="choice in choices track by $index" ng-form="formChoice">
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.itemName" class="form-control" name="item_name" placeholder="Category Item Name" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.itemDesc" class="form-control" name="item_desc" placeholder="Category Description" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" required>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" ng-model="choice.itemView" class="form-control" name="item_count" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]/" placeholder="Category Item View Count" required>
      <p class="help-block" ng-show="formChoice.item_count.$error.pattern">numbers only allowed</p>
      <select id="country" ng-model="choice.states" name="state" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <option value=''>Choose</option>
      City:
      <select id="state" ng-disabled="!choice.states" name="city" ng-model="one">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option ng-repeat="state in choice.states" value="{{state.id}}">{{state.city}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="removeChoice()" class="remove btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="!formChoice.item_name.$dirty||!formChoice.item_desc.$dirty||!formChoice.item_count.$dirty||!formChoice.state.$dirty||!formChoice.city.$dirty||formChoice.item_name.$invalid||formChoice.item_desc.$invalid">close</button>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <button class="addfields btn btn-success" ng-click="addNewChoice()" ng-disabled="frm.$invalid">Add fields</button>
  <button class="addfields btn btn-success" ng-disabled="!frm.item_name.$dirty||!frm.item_desc.$dirty||!frm.item_count.$dirty||!frm.state.$dirty||!frm.city.$dirty||frm.$invalid||frm.item_desc.$invalid ">Save</button>

  <span class="help-block" style="color:red" ng-show="frm.cat_desc.$error.pattern">ERROR:<BR/>text only allowed</span >
  <span class="help-block" style="color:red" ng-show="frm.item_desc.$error.pattern">ERROR:<BR/>text only allowed</span >  
  <span class="help-block" style="color:red" ng-show="frm.cat_name.$error.pattern">ERROR:<BR/>text only allowed</span >
  <span class="help-block" style="color:red" ng-show="frm.item_name.$error.pattern">ERROR:<BR/>text only allowed</span >
  <div id="choicesDisplay">{{ newItemNo }}</div>
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also i want display new Item no

Comment: Ok.  Is that a question?  If so, please be specific.